# How to sort list by currently logged user at top

Tags: android, sorting, collections

I have a list, I need to show the currently logged user at the top of the list.
How can I show it?
I am using Collections.sort method but it only compares string values by userid or username and sorting in ASC or DSC order.

```
Collections.sort(response.getData(), new Comparator<UpcomingParticipantsData>(){
                        public int compare(UpcomingParticipantsData obj1, UpcomingParticipantsData obj2) {
                            // ## Ascending order
                            return obj1.getUid().compareToIgnoreCase(obj2.getUid()); // To compare string values
                            // return Integer.valueOf(obj1.empId).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(obj2.empId)); // To compare integer values

                            // ## Descending order
                            // return obj2.firstName.compareToIgnoreCase(obj1.firstName); // To compare string values
                            // return Integer.valueOf(obj2.empId).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(obj1.empId)); // To compare integer values
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Does `UpcomingParticipantsData` have a property which will indicate the Login date and time ? Add `UpcomingParticipantsData` class  with Question .

Comment: @ADM UpcomingParticipantsData have only 2 parameters 

uid and username

It does not depend on login, what I need is to place the user at top and rest users from 1st index of arraylist, once get response from server.

Comment: That's not sorting . You just need to get the current user and insert it at zero index also remove it first if the list alreay contain it.

Comment: @ADM Okay, can you help me to achieve this ? and is it possible without for loop?